# MFP 8.0 Migration | WL.Client.setHeartBeatInterval function not working

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I downloaded an MFP 6.3 sample project from below URL and migrated to MFP 8.0

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/6.3/working-offline/working-offline/

```
function wlCommonInit(){    
    document.addEventListener(WL.Events.WORKLIGHT_IS_CONNECTED, connectDetected, false); 
    document.addEventListener(WL.Events.WORKLIGHT_IS_DISCONNECTED, disconnectDetected , false);
}

function connectionFailure(){
    alert("Could not connect to the MobileFirst Server.");
    var output = new Date() + "<hr />Working offline";
    $('#info').html(output);
}

function disconnectDetected(){
    var output = new Date() + "<hr />disconnectDetected";
    $('#info').html(output);
}

function connectDetected(){
    var output = new Date() + "<hr />connectDetected";
    $('#info').html(output);
}

function setHeartBeatInterval(interval){
    var output = new Date() + "<hr />heartbeat interval is set to: " + interval;
    $('#info').html(output);
    WL.Client.setHeartBeatInterval(interval);
}
```

`WL.Client.setHeartBeatInterval` function is called. But `WORKLIGHT_IS_CONNECTED, WORKLIGHT_IS_DISCONNECTED` events not triggered in MFP 8.0.

Will `WL.Client.setHeartBeatInterval` is work or not?

Answer (score 0):

`WL.Client.setHeartBeatInterval`
 is valid as of MFP 8.0, and works well.API details [here](http://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/api-ref/wl-client-js-apidoc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Client.html#setHeartBeatInterval).

The events, however are not valid anymore. You can add your custom event listeners and check for connectivity.